# Copy Entire Bitmap Data to the byte Array

Tags: c#, image-processing, ms-media-foundation

I would like to copy the Entire Bitmap Data into the ByteArray May I know , how would i do this ?
I used the below snippet of code

```
   bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,bitmap.PixelFormat);
            int numbytes = bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height;
            byte[] bytedata = new byte[numbytes];
            IntPtr ptr = bmpdata.Scan0;

            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytedata, 0, numbytes);
            return bytedata;
```

But the Values are always zero that is copied into the byteArray

Will this work right ?

Comment: PixelFormat is 24bppRgb, Yes, the stride in this Image case was positive, I was trying to make it work for this case first , but still there is a issue I guess

Comment: Not much to say unless you give more details about the used image. You could just attach it. One very important thing, though: the byte data is not enough. You also need to return the stride to handle the data correctly.

Comment: Side note: you should really perform an `UnlockBits` after you're finished with the `bmpdata` object.

Answer (score 0):

Overall you are copying right, and there is a [sample code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) on MSDN about such copying.

You are generally supposed to copy on a row-by-row basis since rows don't have to be laid out continuously.

If all of the data you are copying are of zeros then the source `bitmap` object is likely to contain no valid data in first place, just blackness.

Comment: Yup, that is right, I am copying it overall, but as u suggested in the Code snippet, I can't change the Value to Red or any other value, as the bitmap Data should be preserved , is there any alternative then?

Comment: You don't _need_ to copy row by row if you preserve the `stride` from the `BitmapData` object. But if you do copy row per row, you should copy the exact amount of used bytes per row (`int lineWidth = (width * bpp + 7) / 8`) into a completely compact array (of size `lineWidth * height`). Do note you need to use two position indicators for the copy process then; the pointer of the BitmapData that increases by the `stride`, and your own array index that increases by `linewidth`.